# How to resolve issue with " Â " appears before currency sign?

Tags: civicontribute, currency

Whenever I export a csv from any report, if it contains a £ sign, there is always Â appears before. How to resolve it please? I am using civicrm 4.6.11, my mysql database characterset is set to "UTF8".

Answer (score 2):

My workaround for this is to immediately convert the CSV file in a text editor such as Notepad++ or UltraEdit.

As soon as it's downloaded I open the CSV as UTF8, then immediately save it as ANSI. It's a bit fiddly, but fixes the £ problem, as well as any unusual characters in names/addresses.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the csv, what software do you use? Are you looking with Excel, and if so is Excel also expecting UTF8?

Comment: yes, I am using Excel 2013. I didn't understand, what do you mean by " is Excel also expecting UTF8?"

Comment: Excel also uses encoding to show you the csv file. If Excel is set to a different encoding you will get strange characters. See http://help.surveygizmo.com/help/article/link/encode-an-excel-file-to-utf-8-or-utf-16